# Laravel 10 Validation - is it possible to merge nested attributes into one

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

This is the error I am getting at the moment:

```
Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#1725 ▼ // resources/views/components/forms/form.blade.php
  #bags: array:1 [▶
    "default" => Illuminate\Support\MessageBag {#1726 ▶
      #messages: array:5 [▶
        "name" => array:1 [▶
          0 => "The name field is required."
        ]
        "description" => array:1 [▶
          0 => "The description field is required."
        ]
        "meta.0" => array:1 [▶
          0 => "If there is addition description for please make it at least 30 characters long"
        ]
        "meta.1" => array:1 [▶
          0 => "If there is addition description for please make it at least 30 characters long"
        ]
        "meta.2" => array:1 [▶
          0 => "If there is addition description for please make it at least 30 characters long"
        ]
      ]
      #format: ":message"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the **Request** class I am trying to do this, but without success:

```
public function attributes(): array
    {
        return [
            'meta.*' => 'meta'
        ];
    }
```

Is it possible to merge all the **meta.1, meta.2 ...** into **meta** error attribute?

Comment: You can override the `failedValidation` method in your Form Request and manipulate the errors / messages before the Exception is thrown